# how to create for loop grep in bash

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

I'm trying to create a for loop that counts the number of keywords in each file within a directory separately.

For Example if a directory has 2 files I would like the for loop to say

```
foo.txt = found 4 keywords
bar.txt = found 3 keywords
```

So far I have written the below but its give the total number keywords from all files instead of for each separate file.

The result I get is

```
7 keywords founds
```

Instead of the desired output above

Here is what I came up with

```
for i in *; do egrep 'The version is out of date|Fixed in|Identified the following' /path/to/directory* | wc -l ; done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use grep's `-c` count option:

```
grep -c <pattern> /path/to/directory/*
```

You'll get something like:

```
bar.txt:2
foo.txt:1
```

Note this will count *lines* matched, not individual patterns matched. So if a pattern appears twice on a line, it will only count once.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for ! Thank you !